# Histogram graph shows 3 elements on top of another, not one after another

Tags: histograms

So my problem is basically what the title says. Instead of [what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WaA.png)  this is what it looks like [resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOspP.png). Should it be like that? Or is it an error?

Comment: Can you clarify? What type of data are you looking at, what is the code you've tried, etc? You'll get better help if you provide enough information about your problem.

Comment: Well @IonGanea I did "bothered to look" but your question is incomplete nevertheless. [Check this guide, if you bother to get some help in the future.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

```
NPMartor = {274., 286.3333, 307.3333, 264.3333, 268.6666, 294.6666, 272.3333, 
   257.6666, 264., 297.6666, 212., 211.51};

NPHumatRad = {287.3333, 292.3333, 274.3333, 264.3333, 289.3333, 263., 
   293.6666, 265.6666, 310.3333, 260.3333, 250.6666, 225.};

NPHumatFoliar = {233.6666, 243.3333, 308., 260.6666, 290., 254.3333, 254.6666,
    237.3333, 293., 237.3333, 198., 200.};
```

The [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)s overlap because the data ranges overlap.

```
NumberLinePlot[
 Interval /@
  MinMax /@
   {NPMartor, NPHumatRad, NPHumatFoliar},
 PlotLegends ->
  {"NPMartor", "NPHumatRad", "NPHumatFoliar"}]
```

[image]

You can separate the data by using [`Histogram3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html)

```
Histogram3D[{{#, 1} & /@ NPMartor, {#, 2} & /@ NPHumatRad, {#, 3} & /@ 
   NPHumatFoliar}, 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[{"NPMartor", "NPHumatRad", "NPHumatFoliar"}, Bottom]]
```

[image]